# javaOptions for custom test configuration with Play/SBT

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1, specs2

I'm using Play Framework 2.1.x and would like to have two test configs one for small tests and the other one for large tests. The large test needs to have custom javaOptions value. I have the following config, however it seems that the javaOptions setting does not get picked up.

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val mySettings = Seq(...)

  val smallTestSettings = Defaults.testSettings ++ Seq(
    testOptions := Seq(Tests.Filter(smallTests))
  )

  val largeTestSettings = Defaults.testSettings ++ Seq(
    testOptions := Seq(Tests.Filter(largeTests)),
    javaOptions ++= Seq("-Dmysetting=1")  // <--- PROBLEM HERE
  )

  lazy val SmallTest = config("smalltest") extend(Test)
  lazy val LargeTest = config("largetest") extend(Test)

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
    .configs(SmallTest)
    .configs(LargeTest)
    .settings(mySettings: _*)
    .settings(inConfig(SmallTest)(smallTestSettings): _*)
    .settings(inConfig(LargeTest)(largeTestSettings): _*)
}
```

Interestingly, if I change the line to:

```
    javaOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Dmysetting=1")
```

then it does get picked up by both the large and small tests. Any ideas on how I can set this custom javaOptions only for the large test config?

Comment: Is it purpose that you kill all previous test settings with :=? To append settings use testOptions ++= Seq(Tests.Filter(largeTests)).

Comment: Not on purpose, I can change that. Is it related to the problem though?

Comment: I don't think so, I just wanted to warn you to prevent bad surprises for future SBT code.

Answer (score 1):

```
  val largeTestSettings = Defaults.testSettings ++ Seq(
    testOptions := Seq(Tests.Filter(largeTests)),
    testOptions in LargeTest += Tests.Argument("-Dmysetting=1")
  )
```

I got the specs2 tests only to read the properties, if they are annotated with the JUnitRunner:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import org.specs2.runner.JUnitRunner

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class LargeScalaTest extends Specification {
  "mysetting should be 1" in {
        System.getProperty("mysetting") must beEqualTo("1")
  }
}
```

My test project is in a branch on [GitHub](https://github.com/schleichardt/stackoverflow-answers/tree/so19676060).

Comment: I added this both to mySettings to and in the line that's marked PROBLEM HERE above -- doesn't work :(

Comment: It should work, check out my test project from GitHub and run: sbt smalltest:test largetest:test

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for putting this together. Your test does work for Java tests, but fails for Scala tests. I sent you a pull request with a demo.

Comment: I'd like to keep my runner to be the default specs runner - you think it's a bug in Specs2 or SBT?